# Xamarin.Forms Android Resources$NotFoundException for drawable xml resource

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have followed [this guide](https://alexdunn.org/2017/02/07/creating-a-splash-page-for-xamarin-forms-android/) to create a splash screen for Android using Xamarin Forms. However, an exception is being thrown while debugging:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/launchscreen.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020093
```

I am sure the xml is in the Resources/drawable folder and Build Action is set to AndroidResource. I have even opened the APK and the launchscreen.xml is there.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear what the issue is, can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've solved this and will explain below. I can still post a demo code. It's just like the one in the guide refered above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the Xamarin's AppCompat version plus the configuration I had. It went away after some steps I took. I can't be sure which solved it, but here is what I have done:

- Updated my VS2017 to 15.3.2.
- Installed the newer Android SDK versions through Android SDK Manager. I was developing with API Level 23. I've installed 24 and 25.
- Finaly, I've updated the AppCompat packages from version 23 to version 25. I believe this last might have solved it all, although the previous step was a requirement for this update.

Answer (score 0):

My layout was not rendering it was showing some Resource$not found .
I just cleaned the build and restarted my system and guess what it is back again every thing is fine.

The problem started after i had added custom theme.xml to my project.

Comment: Why did i get -1 ?